# Using matrix for FAQ's

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Using EE to display FAQ's on my site. Each FAQ will have a link to an individual page for SEO reasons. I have two options:

1: Using EE's native channel entries and adding FAQ's individually/importing them as a batch with DataGrab.

2: Using a matrix field and having them all stored in one channel entry.

To get the faq's to display as separate urls I will use the additional matrix_url_title field type:  https://github.com/pixelandtonic/matrix_url_title.

Now to me the standard entries way seems more efficient. However, can someone tell me which one is the best way in terms of Database queries etc.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the differences DB queries-wise, but in terms of user experience, you may find entries the way to go.  For example, as the number of FAQs increases, it may be useful to group them by categories, for example - natively pretty simple to do as entries.  Not to mention the admin's entry workflow would be the same as it would be everywhere else.  The advantage Matrix offers, potentially, is actively determining order.  To do that with entries natively can be a bit of a pain (though [Low Reorder](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-reorder) makes that pretty simple).

Comment: Or alternatively use a playa field on the main FAQ page to reorder...

Comment: I second this. I have experimented both ways and ran into a brick wall in one instance trying to add more fields to a matrix field than what EE liked. It essentially crashed my entries that used that field group. The entries still displayed, but I couldn't create or edit any entries after adding like the 7th matrix field. and I had to remove data from the db the old fashion way to get it to work again then delete the matrix field and rebuild it.   :)

Answer (score 1):

I also like the idea of using entries instead of matrix fields - both for ease of maintenance, and so that - unless you're already using Matrix somehow else on this same site - to minimize the number of plugins/extensions being used.

It's possible to create a channel for the FAQ entries, and add a field to that channel that lets you specify the entry-order / question-order.

Answer (score 0):

In the last couple of sites that I built that had FAQs, they were less than 20 questions per faq. I didn't set up a channel, but instead used a Low Variable that used the matrix field type. Super easy to use, easy to re-order and the clients are very happy with it.

If categories were required then I would take one of two options, create a whole new matrix per category or add a new column with a dropdown/p&T pill and have the category chosen on a per row basis. In this case in the matrix code you'd use matrix search {my_matrix_field search:age=">=16"}